# What are helpful pieces of information to have when answering a CiviCRM SE question?

Tags: discussion

We often find ourselves asking for the same information from people asking questions - Civi version, CMS software, etc.

Many applications have a "Troubleshooting Info" page that collects all this information in one place.  [I've opened an issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16622) on the issue tracker to add such a page in CiviCRM.

So my question is: What information should we be collecting on such a page?

Answer (score 1):

As much as we can get!

- CiviCRM version
- PHP version
- MySQL version and flavor (Percona, MariaDB, etc), if that's discoverable via PHP
- Web server type (Apache, Nginx, etc) and version
- Server OS and version
- If something like Memcached or Redis is present and in use